# How can i search for a specific message in a chat in python? (pyTelegramBotAPI)

Tags: python, api, bots, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm programming a Telegram bot. I want to search for a specific message in a telegram channel and get its message id. Is it possible? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you aren't able to search though messages (in a specific chat) by just using Telegram's bot API. You need an MTProto client to do that. You can use pyrogram or telethon to interface with MTProto then use messages.search.

But, there is a catch. If the message you're searching is in a channel, you can webscrape `https://t.me/s/CHANNELUSERNAME` with a library like BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Thx for the tip! And is there any way to get the searched messages id with any of these methods?